# Tableau - Data blending

Tags: tableau-api, data-analysis

The columns in the secondary datasource with data blending in Tableau are not geo-mapped (The latitude and longitude measures are disabled). I am not able to do filled and symbol maps.

[image]

Datasource1 : SQL DB Table; Datasource2 : Excel file;

Is there an another way to join or blend the data in two different datasources?

Comment: Yes, but only in v10. It looks like you are on v9. Can you upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately the IT has standardized 9.1 has the version across the company

Comment: That's too bad. For v9 you can either use data blending (as you've tried) or you would need to import that Excel file into your SQL database.

Comment: Or if you can't create tables in your database, you could export the data from your database into an Excel or CSV file, and then join two tabs in the same Excel file or two CSV files.

Comment: Very helpful of the IT staff to put the user's needs first.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to add the other dataset, below is an image for the same:

[image]
2. Now to add the columns of both the datasets in **Data Source**,**Join** is performed.
Below is an image for the same:

[image]

Here, any of four types of **join** can be performed.